# set value of textbox from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using asp and have some textboxes where I want to set the value from code behind. The code below is wrapped inside an asp:DetailsView.

The Textbox I want to get and set value of is InsertItemTemplate with ID=strPositionsName

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="strPositionName">
     <InsertItemTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="strPositionName" Width="380px" MaxLength="49" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("strPositionName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
     </InsertItemTemplate>
     <EditItemTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" Width="380px" MaxLength="49" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("strPositionName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
     </EditItemTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Width="380px" Text='<%# Bind("strPositionName") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I managed to get the value by:

```
var testName = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("strPositionName")).Text;
```

So I tried using this:

```
((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("strPositionName")).Text = "textboxvalue";
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Where did you set the value? Which event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Code

```
TextBox _txtPositionName=(TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("strPositionName");
if(_txtPositionName!=null)
 _txtPositionName.Text="textboxvalue";
```